# Problem with Protobuf

Tags: c#, .net, protobuf-net

I switched to work on another computer, I installed visual C# express and protoBuf-net,
and then I copied the source of the project to the other computer.
Now when I open the project on the second computer, the program does not serialize and deserialize the data.

When I'm debugging, every time I step into a piece of code using Protobuf, I get this message:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll check the project files for a problem (that _fixed looks *highly* suspicious) but unless you *need* the "v2" features it may be easier to use the pre-built dll that can be downloaded. Since this appears to relate to pre-release software it may be easier to e-mail me (as the author) directly.

For info, there are some bat files in the repo that should cleanly build the core project for common .net versions. I can't check right now (away from PC).

Comment: Do you mean the r282 that contains the .dll files? I did downloaded the packge

Comment: @Gilad - yes, that has pre-built dlls for various .net versions. NET30 is probably the most appropriate.